# Pointers for 2D arrays

Tags: c, pointers

This is a question from Microsoft Test:

```
 main()
    {
        int a[2][3]= { (1,2,3),(4,5,6)};
        int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];
        printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1],(*ptr)[2]);
        ptr+=1;
        printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1],(*ptr)[2]);

    }
```

Options given are:

1. segmentation fault
2. compiler error
3. bus error
4. run time error

I ran this code and I didn't get any of this. I got the following answer:

```
6 0   
0 0
```

Can you please help me understand what's happening?

Comment: `main` is missing a return type. This should cause a compile error unless you are using a very old or very liberal compiler.

Comment: thanx :D i didn't pay attention to it

Answer (score 8):

The main issue is this line:

```
    int a[2][3]= { (1,2,3),(4,5,6)};
```

It is using parentheses instead of braces.  The result of (1,2,3) is just 3, and the result of (4,5,6) is just 6.  So this is equivalent to:

```
    int a[2][3]= { 3,6 };
```

Which in turn is equivalent to

```
    int a[2][3] = { {3,6,0}, {0,0,0} };
```

This line makes ptr point to a[0]:

```
    int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];
```

This line

```
    printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1],(*ptr)[2]);
```

is then equivalent to

```
    printf("%d %d\n", (*&a[0])[1],(*&a[0])[2]);
```

which can be simplified to

```
    printf("%d %d\n", (a[0])[1],(a[0])[2]);
```

or just

```
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0][1],a[0][2]);
```

This line

```
    ptr+=1;
```

makes ptr point to the next element of a, so it is equivalent to

```
    ptr=&a[1];
```

so the next line simplifies to

```
    printf("%d %d\n", a[1][1],a[1][2]);
```

The program effectively prints a[0][1], a[0][2], a[1][1] and a[1][2], so that's why you get 6,0,0,0.

Charles Baley points out that main() is missing the return type.  This may be what they are getting at.  The compiler would normally at least give a warning about that.

Comment: A C89 compiler like MS Visual C isn't obliged to complain about the lack of return type on `main()`.

Comment: thanx :D and as charles pointed out i missed return statement. But, can you tell me what (*ptr)[3] = &a[0] is doing specifically?

Comment: It (`int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];`) defines `ptr` as a pointer to an array of 3 integers and initializes it with a pointer to the first array of 3 integers in `a`.

Comment: So what if I had an array suppose {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}} and I had (*ptr)[3] = &a[0]? What are the arrays the (ptr) and (ptr+1) point to?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal: If you didn't change the type of the array, then the extra values would be ignored.  If you did change the type of a to int a[2][4], then the type of ptr would be incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you copied the text correctly?

`(1,2,3)` is an expression with two sequence or comma (`,`) operators; its value is 3. Likewise, the value of `(4,5,6)` is 6.  This is the 6 that is being printed at `a[0][1]` (since ptr points to `a[0]` and you print `(*ptr)[1]`); the 0 is `a[0][2]`, which has default initialization of 0. Then you increment `ptr`, pointing it to `a[1]`, so you print `a[1][1]` and `a[1][2]`, which also have default initialization of 0.